# Bind view based NSTableView to an NSArrayController

Tags: binding, nsarraycontroller, nstablecellview

I want to bind programmatically my NSTableView to an NSArrayController.

Everything works fine with Cell-Based Table using:

```
[[table tableColumns][0] bind:NSValueBinding toObject:board.dataSource withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.name" options:nil];
```

but when I try to bind to a view based table….how it should work?
I suppose to bind "arrangedObjects" to the column and then each property of my arrangedObjects's nth element to an object of my NSTableCellView…but how can I make it programmatically?

I've tried to access at NSTableColumn's view's class but the only method I've found is .dataCell and it returns an NSTextFieldCell not the class I would to use for my table (an NSTableCellView).

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

For a View-based TableView you need to bind the NSArrayController arrangedObjects to the tableView content.

*Ignore the column, which is very different to cell-based TableViews.*

Bind the Table Cell View to the NSArrayController selection and then use a model key of observationInfo.

Finally bind the views, eg Text View to the NSCell View with model key objectValue.name, where name is some property of the entity being represented in the table.

If you are using core data then set up the NSArrayController parameter to be the managedObjectContext, set it to type entity and provide the entity name and tick the prepares content check box.

Comment: I am not able to see in Xcode 5 for this `Bind the Table Cell View to the NSArrayController selection and then use a model key of observationInfo.` Could you please update the answer with some screen shots, please.